# Как можно укоротить метод? с#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    double x = double.Parse(textBox1.Text);
    int fst = comboBox1.SelectedIndex;
    int scn = comboBox2.SelectedIndex;

    switch (fst)
    {
        case 0:
            switch (scn)
            {
                case 0:
                    label1.Text = x.ToString();
                    break;
                case 1:
                    label1.Text = (x / 1000).ToString();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    label1.Text = (x / 1000000).ToString();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    label1.Text = (x * 1000).ToString();
                    break;
                case 4:
                    label1.Text = (x * 0.00220462).ToString();
                    break;
            }
            break;
        case 1:
            switch (scn)
            {
                case 0:
                    label1.Text = (x * 1000) .ToString();
                    break;
                case 1:
                    label1.Text = x.ToString();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    label1.Text = (x / 1000).ToString();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    label1.Text = (x * 1000000).ToString();
                    break;
                case 4:
                    label1.Text = (x * 2.20462).ToString();
                    break;
            }
            break;
        case 2:
            switch (scn)
            {
                case 0:
                    label1.Text = (x * 1000000).ToString();
                    break;
                case 1:
                    label1.Text = (x * 1000).ToString();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    label1.Text = x.ToString();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    label1.Text = (x * 1000000000).ToString();
                    break;
                case 4:
                    label1.Text = (x * 2204.62).ToString();
                    break;
            }
            break;
        case 3:
            switch (scn)
            {
                case 0:
                    label1.Text = (x / 1000).ToString();
                    break;
                case 1:
                    label1.Text = (x / 1000000).ToString();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    label1.Text = (x / 1000000000).ToString();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    label1.Text = x.ToString();
                    break;
                case 4:
                    label1.Text = (x * 0.00000220462).ToString();
                    break;
            }
            break;
        case 4:
            switch (scn)
            {
                case 0:
                    label1.Text = (x * 453.59).ToString();
                    break;
                case 1:
                    label1.Text = (x * 0.45359).ToString();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    label1.Text = (x * 0.00045359).ToString();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    label1.Text = (x * 453590).ToString();
                    break;
                case 4:
                    label1.Text = x.ToString();
                    break;
            }
            break;
    }
        
}
```

Comment: Что этот код делает то? Он работает вообще? Версия дотнета какая? UI покажите и смысл кода расскажите.

Comment: В первом приближении - запихать ваши множители в список списков и брать их оттуда по индексам. Кода будет пара строк, основное место займёт инициализация списка списков.

Comment: @CrazyElf в первом приближении здесь куча магических чисел, очень слабо поддающихся эвристике. Наверняка зная исходный смысл этого кода возможно избавиться и от свичей и от магических чисел полностью, уложив код в 3-4 строки. Это [XY-вопрос](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/709/373567).

Comment: @aepot Так то да, но эвристика для меня пока не очевидна. Я сторонник того, чтобы предлагать решения разного уровня понимания проблемы, а не только одно абсолютно идеальное.

Comment: @CrazyElf ну да, 4 строки по сути и получилось без свичей вообще.

Answer (score 1):

Наверное, сейчас можно ещё проще списки инициализировать, я точно не помню, но суть примерно такая:

```cs
var data = new List<List<double>>
{
    new List<double>{ 1, 1.0/100, 1.0/1000000, ... },
    new List<double>{ 1000, 1, 1.0/1000, ... },
    ...
};
label1.Text = (x * data[fst][scn]).ToString();
```

Только инициализация списков и одна строчка кода, никакой лишней копипасты. Если очень хочется, можно вообще данные в `json` поместить и оттуда забирать, тогда ещё компактнее наверное будет.

Comment: 1) это ответ-угадайка, 2) использование списков там, где можно использовать массивы - плохой пример новичку, 3) с точки зрения перфа и расхода ресурсов свич выгоднее, в худшем случае в форме свич-выражения можно оформить. Минус не буду ставить, но хотелось бы, чтобы вы еще раз подумали над содержимым ответа.

Comment: @aepot Насчёт списков и массивов согласен. Я просто настолько привык к питону и его простому синтаксису, что забыл уже, как в C# инициализации пишутся (  Свитч выгоднее, но, думаю, тогда бы не стоял вопрос как код упростить. Учитывая, что всё это пишется в лейбл, думаю, скорость тут явно не главное вообще )

Comment: Проведите базовую эвристику кода, раз уж вы без описания решили его понять. Верхний уровень: 0 = 1, 1 = 1000, 2 = 1000 * 1000, 3 = 0.001, 4 = 1 / 0.00220462. Нижний уровень: 1 / верхний уровень.

Comment: наугад без проверок, получается как-то так `const double x = 1000; const double y = 453.59; double[] k = new double[] { 1, x, x * x, 1 / x, y }; double result = k[fct] / k[scn]; label1.Text = result.ToString();`